# Ad network redirecting to safari or app download every 5 seconds - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, mobfox

I've had a lot of users complain about my ads automatically redirecting them to safari or iOS app store every 5 seconds without even pressing the ad. Anyone have this issue? I can't seem to pinpoint the problem or even the ad network.

The app that had the issue was using Mobfox, Admob, Millennium Media and I've disabled Mobfox and Millennium and blocked all gaming ads on Admob hoping this will go away.

Anyone experienced similar issues lately that has successfully pinpointed the ad network and the category?

Comment: here's the URL that it's being redirected to: http://srv1.quality-ueser-converts.com

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run into such cases with my configs of admob, MM and Mopub. But I have heard there are some small ad networks running ads with timer to triger auto-redirect. I think the only way u can try is to block one by one to identify which one serves the bad ad. Good luck.